# How to send buffer bigger than 256kByte with boost asio on OSX, works fine on WIN

Tags: macos, boost-asio

I have a simple client server approach sending char buffers using tcp socket with boost asio on OSX. When I use a buffer bigger than 256kBytes I get a Memory Access error. It seems to happen on the Server side. But nonetheless, the exact same code with bigger buffer sizes than 256kBytes is working perfectly on Windows!

gdb on OSX tells me

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000001002bebb8
[Switching to process 15955 thread 0x2003]
0x0000000100012920 in connectionThread::operator() ()
```

I'm wondering if there is a OS specific memory allocation issue I have to be aware of. Boost Asio docs weren't really helpful.

I do not want to split the buffer! I want to send an entire buffer, which could have a size up to 921600Bytes. Which already works perfectly on windows with boost asio.

Message

```
char data[307200];
```

Client side SEND msg

```
void send( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& s ) const {
    try {
        boost::asio::write( s, boost::asio::buffer( data, data_size));
    }
    catch( std::exception e ) {
        throw std::runtime_error("message send error | " + std::string( e.what() ) );
    }
}
```

Server side READ msg

```
void read( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& s ) {
    try {
        // Read data
        boost::asio::read( s, boost::asio::buffer( &data, data_size ));
    }
    catch( std::exception e ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "message read error | " + std::string( e.what() ) );
    }
}
```

backtrace

```
    Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000001002bebb8
[Switching to process 17916 thread 0x2003]
0x0000000100012920 in connectionThread::operator() ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000100012920 in connectionThread::operator() ()
#1  0x000000010000679d in boost::_mfi::mf1<void, connectionThread, boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >&>::operator() ()
#2  0x00000001000068ca in boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<connectionThread*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf1<void, connectionThread, boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >&>, boost::_bi::list0> ()
#3  0x000000010000690a in boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, connectionThread, boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<connectionThread*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > >::operator() ()
#4  0x0000000100006928 in boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, connectionThread, boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<connectionThread*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > >::run ()
#5  0x000000010006b699 in thread_proxy (param=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:121
#6  0x00007fff8094cfd6 in _pthread_start ()
#7  0x00007fff8094ce89 in thread_start ()
(gdb)
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: How do you declare data_size? Can you post the complete stack trace AND the operator which actually used invalid memory?

Comment: You say the message can have up to 921600 Bytes, but your data is only declared with 307200 bytes?

Comment: @Andrew data_size = sizeof(char) * 307200; and i added the backtrace, the connection between client and server is established in a separate thread. there seems to be a problem whenever the buffer exceeds 256000Bytes

Comment: @Chad probably not clearly explained, my bad. In this example I just used 307200 Bytes, which corresponds to a 640x480px char luminance 1 channel image, if I would use RGB 3 channels image I would have 921600 Bytes. but this is somehow a detail, because I reach the limit already with 256000 Bytes

Comment: it looks like you have a bug in your operator(). If you want people to find this bug, you might want to post the source code of that function